# Create case when statement in MySQL to identify repeat callers over a given time frame

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been tasked at work to identify repeat callers in MySQL. I have a datetime for when the interaction begins, a callers phone number as well as a queue that it entered. I am looking to add a casewhen statement that will add a column to my results with either a 1, if the same combination of phone number and queue is recorded in the last 14 days, and a 0 if it wasnt.

[image: I have included an image to show how I would like the column to work.]

Notable things about the image:

1. Row 6 is a 0 due to the fact the queues on row 4 and 6 do not match. Row 8 then has a 1 because rows 4 and 8 match.
2. Due to the phone number and queues matching on rows 3 and 7, row 7 has been given a 1. There is then another repeat call on row 10. Due to a 1 already being in one of the duplicates in its 14 day lookback, I want this to return a 0.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Really not sure where to even start.

Comment: Join the table with itself to find rows with matching phone numbers and queues, but different times.

Comment: Pictures are not useful. Post textual formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts with sample data and add desired output for it.